# excel.link package not working with R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again"

Tags: r

I am not able to use excel.link package with R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22) -- "Taking Off Again". The code I am trying to use worked on previous versions. Has anyone else experienced the same problem and found a way to fix it?

For example the following code used to open a new excel sheet with the iris dataset in it

```
ExcelPrint = function(rObject) {
  library(excel.link)
  myExcelProcess = COMCreate("Excel.Application")
  xl.workbook.add()
  excelRange = myExcelProcess[["ActiveSheet"]]$Range("A1:A1")
  xl.write(rObject, excelRange, row.names = FALSE)
} 

ExcelPrint(iris)
```

Comment: I tried this and did not get an error in my `R` console. My `R` session aborted with a fatal error. What happens when you run this code?

Comment: Have you tried alternative pavkages such as `openxlsx`?

Comment: Ben Norris, I am getting "To Daniela Khazova who constantly inspires me...
Error: Invalid class string
In addition: Warning message:
In getCOMInstance(name, force = TRUE, silent = TRUE) :
 
 Error: Invalid class string" but the behaviour you got happend on my other PC

Comment: Allan Cameron, what I am trying to achive is the aility to open an excel with my dataset in it. I do not know how to do this with openxlsx. I would be thankful if you provided a way.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following function. It uses openxlsx package as Allan mentioned in the comments and writes an xlsx file to disc before using shell command to open it.

```
library(openxlsx)

quickExcelPrint=function(rObject,filename="r_excel_tmp.xlsx",overwrite=FALSE){
  if (filename %in% dir() & overwrite==FALSE){
    stop(paste0("Excel filename ",filename," already exists! Please either specify another filename or set overwrite to TRUE."))
  } else{
    write.xlsx(rObject, filename)
    shell(paste0("start excel ",filename))
  }
}
```

Example

```
quickExcelPrint(iris,overwrite = T)
```